# Get disconnect from speech recognition service

Tags: android, speech-recognition, destroy

If I use the speech recognition like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
```

do some setting ....
and make

```
startActivityForResult(intent, SystemData.VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Is there a way to stop the service (like destroy) using the some intent or in any other way?

Thanks
Bar.

Comment: From what I see, you are starting an activity, not a service. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to stop the speech recognition service.
I make a general variable of type SpeechRecognizer.

Put it at the beginning of the class like that:

private SpeechRecognizer speech = null;

Then in the speech initialization I connect it to a listener and use it in the intent like this:

```
    speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getActivity());

    speech.setRecognitionListener(this);

    Intent recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
```

Then at any part of this class if I want to active the speech I use this:

speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);

and to stop it I do this:

speech.stopListening();

so the listener is the  key for activity of speech.

Answer (score -1):

First add two buttons [buttonStart and buttonStop]  to your activity xml and then
In the activity that contains the code in ur question add  :
   @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

```
    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  public void onClick(View src) {
    switch (src.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonStart:
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting srvice");
      startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
      break;
    case R.id.buttonStop:
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
      stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
      break;
    }
  }
```

MyService.java

```
mport android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.braincandy);
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        player.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't clear myself. The service I want to stop is not part of my program. It is the speech recognition service of the Android so I can't interrupt inside it. I want to know if there any command I can send it to stop it for processing( In a state where it wait for any speech but nobady talk for a long time). So I want to stop it after didn't get replay for predefine time. So it want make a situation where I decide to go on and then I get an answer which is not relevant and not connect to anything anymore.